# cannot resolve method getActionBar in FragmentActivity Support Library

Tags: intellij-idea, android-actionbar, android-manifest

I opened only untitled project in intellij idea and wrote `getActionBar()` there is:

```
  java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getActionBar()
  location: class com.example.untitled.MyActivity
```

and Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.untitled"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
    <application android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="MyActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

what is reason of this?

Comment: extend ActionBarActivity instead of FragmentActivity